# How to submit selected checkboxes and group name as an objects within an array

Tags: angularjs

I need to pass selected checkbox object data alone into array on form submit.

service returning json data:

```
[
  {
    "groupName" : "A",
    "groups": [
        "Painting",
        "coloring"
      ]
  },
  {
    "groupName" : "B",
    "groups": [
        "drawing",
        "writing"
      ]
  }
]
```

service expected format when user selected couple of check boxes and submit form:

```
{
 "groups": [ 
  {
    "category": "A",
    "subCategory": "coloring"
  },
  {
    "category": "B",
    "subCategory": "writing"    
  }
 ]
}
```

My controller:

```
<div ng-controller="groupCtrl">
<form class="form" name="form" role="form" ng-submit="groupData()" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
        <div ng-repeat="groups in groupsList">
            <p class="category">{{groups.groupName}}</p>
            <p ng-repeat="group in groups.groups" >
                <input type="checkbox" id="group" name="{{group}}" class="group" value="{{group}}" ng-model="groups"> {{group}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller("groupCtrl", function($rootScope, $scope, $state, $http) {
    $http.get('group.json').success(function(groupsList) {
        $scope.groupsList = groupsList;
    });

    $scope.groups = {

    }
    $scope.groupData = function () {
        $http.post('<service endpoint>', $scope.groups, {

        })
        .success(function(){
            console.log("success");
        })
        .error(function(){
            console.log("failed.");
        });
    }

});
```

I am new to angular. Looking for help on how to construct array object in controller and update array object on user select/un-select check boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would put api logic into a service like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
//service to handle api communication
.service('apiService', ['$http', function($http) {
   return {
     getGroups: function() {
       return $http.get('http://superapi.com');
     }
   }
 }])
```

Then you need to call the api service from the controller and build up your view model:

```
api.getGroups().then(function(res) {
    //JSON.parse will not be needed if your API returns a JSON body with application/json set as content-type
    $scope.groupsList = JSON.parse(res.data.data);
    //Build up the view model.
    $scope.groupsList.forEach(function(g) {
      $scope.selectedGroups.groups.push({
        category: g.groupName,
        subCategory: []
      });
    });
  },
  function(error) {
            //handle API errors gracefully here.
  });
```

Then you can use ng-model on the form components to populate it with data

```
  <form class="form" name="form" role="form" ng-submit="groupData()" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
    <div ng-repeat="groups in groupsList track by $index">
      <p class="category">{{groups.groupName}}</p>
      <p ng-repeat="group in groups.groups track by $index">
        <input ng-model="selectedGroups.groups[$parent.$index].subCategory" type="checkbox" id="group" name="{{group}}" class="group" ng-true-value="'{{group}}'" ng-init="checked=''" ng-false-value="''"> {{group}}
      </p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
  </form>
```

Since your api response model has a double nested hierarchy, we need two nested ng-repeat loops. We can then leverage the fact that ng-repeat creates a child scope, and the parent scope is accessible by using $parent. That way we can use that information to bind to the correct part of the view model with ng-model.

```
ng-model="selectedGroups.groups[$parent.$index].subCategory"
```

$parent.$index is the first ng-repeat groups in groupsList

If you want to be able to select more than one subcategory, you can just bind nd-model to each subcategory's index in an array like this:

```
ng-model="selectedGroups.groups[$parent.$index].subCategory[$index]"
```

This will use the index of the subCategory to bind to a specific position in an array.

here is a working example of that :

https://jsfiddle.net/zzq16t8u/4/

Here is a working JSFiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/zzq16t8u/3/

Now when you want to map to the request model specified by the system, you will need to handle this in the function handled by the form submit. You could do something clever with ng-true-value, but then you would still need to do a JSON.parse on your data, as it can only work on strings. And I my opinion handling the mapping to the request model is better done once you prepare to make the request.

```
$scope.groupData = function() {
  // map data to the request model specified
  var requestModel = {
    groups: []
  };
  $scope.selectedGroups.forEach(function(group) {
    group.subCategory.forEach(function(subCat) {
      requestModel.groups.push({
        category: group.category,
        subCategory: subCat
      });
    });
  });
```

Here is a working JSFiddle of everything, note that I have simplified the view model here, since we no longer bind directly to the request model.

https://jsfiddle.net/zzq16t8u/15/

Please note that the JSON.parse is only necessary here, as I was unable to figure out how to get the JSFiddle echo service to return json as real json, and not a string, and the api service in the example uses this echo service to mock a real http response, so that will need to be replace by a real http call - as I showed in this answer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing working example! It really helps. Currently only one option (check box) can select in each group. Do you know the solution to select multiple options in same group (ex: select Painting, Coloring options from A group)

Comment: Yes, see my updated answer. I misunderstood your original question to mean that you only wanted one sub category per group to be selected at once. Version 4 of the JSFiddle let's you select as many subcategories as there are in each group. I added the explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Do we have an option to update post json data as like below since service expected in below format. {"groups": [ {"category":"A","subCategory": "Painting"}, {"category":"A","subCategory": "Coloring"},{"category":"B","subCategory": "Writing"}  ]}

Comment: Glad to help, are you satisfied with this answer? Or do you require more information?

Comment: If you feel my answer, or any other that might show up was what you wanted, please mark it as "accepted".

Comment: I want to display an error on form submit until user selected one of the checkbox. Could you help me sharing code reference.